# PHP+HTML Syntax

Tags: php, html, escaping

I am trying to get a webpage to display four divs that will hold an img and a description. I would like to use a loop because I will have other pages with many of these divs. Here is the code I am using now:

```
for ($i=0;$i<4;$i++)
{
    echo '<div class="item">
    <img src="IMGs\\' . $items[$i]["ImgFilename"] . '" />
    <h6 class="panel">Description</h6>
    </div>';
}
```

I believe the problem is that I am not escaping the correct way. I have been searching for a while but cannot find the right combination. Files are stored in IMGs\file.jpg where file.jpg is pulled from the array.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your escaping seems fine to me. However, I think the problem is with the double backslash. Eg, remove the `\\` and replace it with `/` So that line becomes:

`<img src="IMGs/' . $items[$i]["ImgFilename"] . '" />`

Answer (score 1):

U dont need to escape this.
change this:

```
<img src="IMGs\\' . $items[$i]["ImgFilename"] . '" />
```

to `<img src="IMGs/' . $items[$i]["ImgFilename"] . '" />`

Answer (score 1):

You can lay that code out a little better by breaking in/out of PHP as required, here's a quick example:-

```
<?php for($index = 0; $index < 4; $index++): ?>
    <div class="item">
        <img src="IMGs/<?php echo $items[$index]["ImgFilename"]; ?>" />
        <h6 class="panel">Description</h6>
    </div>
<?php endfor; ?>
```

Comment: That looks a bit ...dont know ...with all those extra in/outs of php's parser :) If you would go that route, i would advise using the php shorthand tag `<?=`

Comment: I get that. It reads better, for me at least. :) Note, short tags `<?=` aren't always available and may require modifications to the `php.ini` to enable.

Comment: @yossarian you mean that HTML looks like HTML, correctly indented, highlighted and without any bloated escaping? That's right, it's a shock to see that after all-grey flat PHP string with a lot of punctuation.

Comment: i prefer `echo '<div class="item">
    <img src="IMGs/{$items[$i]["ImgFilename"]}" />
    <h6 class="panel">Description</h6>
    </div>';` and would prefer antony's idea if there was no other php (in this case the `for`) was involved

Comment: @AnthonySterling quite contrarary, `<?=` are always avaliable.

Comment: @nl-x that's good but sometimes we need to use a PHP variable or two in output

Comment: I guess it's a matter of preference. I think for small blocks of HTML php can easily be mixed in. For larger chunks, yes it would definitely be advisable to use php for php, HTML for HTML.

Comment: @YourCommonSense i dont understand you. or you didnt read my comment correctly

Comment: @YourCommonSense No. php short tags are NOT always enabled by default